# Colour schemes in the Android App

Tags: feature-request, android-app

In the Android app, there is no separate colour for the badges of other users as seen under questions, like here:

> [image: colour scheme in SE app1]

*I've blurred out the username to make the question general and not specific.*

This should be implemented as we see different colours for badges in the Web version, both mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshot given:

- Text outline on the site name
- Black badges
- Black timestamp
- Lack of color variation; only black text

It seems you're using some kind of accessibility, e.g. "High contrast text".

Since the badge is actually a "circle" character, not an image, it gets affected by the change. If that's the case, then Stack Exchange can't do anything because the Android system forces the text color to be black or white-with-black-outline to increase the contrast.

Comparison between normal contrast & high contrast on Nexus 5, Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1):

> [image: normal contrast] [image: high contrast]
>
> <sup>Click the image to see in full size</sup>

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know that it was on. Thanks a lot.